# Python pyodbc IM002 database problem connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, connection, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a database using pyodbs but I have this error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)').

I can't find a nice procedure to solve this problem, anyone can help me?
This is my code:

```
import pyodbc
server='tcp:univerity_server_name'
database= 'db_name'
username='us_name'
password='pw'
connectionString='DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+' DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
```

Thanksss

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have install ODBC Driver 17, so now it works.